# Auto update Kusto to pull todays date but specific time

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am very new to Kusto queries and I have one that is giving me the proper data that I export to Excel to manage. My only problem is that I only care (right now) about yesterday and today in two separate Sheets. I can manually change the datetime with the information but I would like to be able to just refresh the data and it pull the newest number.

It sounds pretty simple but I cannot figure out how to specify the exact time I want.  Has to be from 2 am day 1 until 1:59 day 2

Thanks

```
['Telemetry.WorkStation']
| where NexusUid == "08463c7b-fe37-43b6-a0d2-237472b9774d"
| where TelemetryLocalTimeStamp >= make_datetime(2023,2,15,2,0,0) and TelemetryLocalTimeStamp < make_datetime(2023,2,16,01,59,0)

| where NumberOfBinPresentations >0
```

Answer (score 1):

[ago()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/agofunction), [now()](https://now()), [startofday()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofdayfunction) and some datetime arithmetic.

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let ['Telemetry.WorkStation'] = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend NexusUid = "08463c7b-fe37-43b6-a0d2-237472b9774d", TelemetryLocalTimeStamp = ago(2d * rand()));
// Solution starts here.
['Telemetry.WorkStation']
| where NexusUid == "08463c7b-fe37-43b6-a0d2-237472b9774d"
| where TelemetryLocalTimeStamp >= startofday(ago(1d)) + 2h
    and TelemetryLocalTimeStamp < startofday(now()) + 2h
| summarize count(), min(TelemetryLocalTimeStamp), max(TelemetryLocalTimeStamp)
```

| count_ | min_TelemetryLocalTimeStamp | max_TelemetryLocalTimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500539 | 2023-02-15T02:00:00.0162031Z | 2023-02-16T01:59:59.8883692Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42QzW7CMBCE73mKEReclvCTRKRVS5%20g4gJVD6iHBW/AamxHjiOg4uFraIu4ROoePTuz33g0woJ0XTEkecKWDTvyypoh5tajJudhS/gdo7FVe1Giij1W/SVXrNm74/Ddus%20Fv9j6H5hBk2enqFJfLByZLUOhdFZjAm8xGV8Gjec6vJzAB89GYs6HtnlTMgT0xg/5NNsU66TkrEjybD1NaCzTJM2KvEjXj0WRy94AV4RXu6FqqTQHDF2HBNpakUrcIdyXIo7jp2gUqv5WCLdDsQY7djyMOqtEJ%20zPKzdo/2W7WrsQX2Y/ELaUdBRn3ImMY9wj3UUIE7A7vc%203VmP34s94QtNqTS58PDa2NV7EA2hlREfSWaVDp/oNpHTOqh0CAAA=)